# Read a txt file every first, 2nd and 3rd line and save in 3 different lists

Tags: python, iteration, text-files

I have a huge constant-format text file like this:

```
first line
2nd line
3rd line 
#Mi Mj
#Ni Nj Nk
#Pi Pj
#----------- The numeric values start here ------
M0 M1
N0 N1 N2
P0 P1
M1 M2
N1 N2 N3
P1 P2
M2 M3
N2 N2 N3
P2 P3
...
```

I need to skip 1st to 7th lines and read the file after 7th line every 1st, 2nd and 3rd then save it into three different lists.

I managed to do it for every 1st line in my code by skipping 2 others, but not for every 2nd and 3rd line. How ever using two times next(fileobject) is not an efficient way. So can anyone tells me how can I do it the best for huge files?
I need such a result at the end:

```
list1 = [M0, M1, M1, M2, M2, M3]
list2= [N0,N1,N2,N1, N2,N3,N2,N2, N3]
list3= [P0, P1, P1, P2,P2, P3]
```

Here is my code:

```
    # Python 3
myfile = open('myfile.txt', 'r')

m,n,p = [], [], []

for line in myfile:
    ll = line.strip()  # string
    if not ll.startswith("#"):
        row = ll.split()  # list
        print(row)
        try:
            m.append(row[0]) # append first column of every third line
        except IndexError:
            print('There is not a standard line: ', line)
        next(myfile)
        next(myfile)
print(m)
myfile.close()
```

Comment: How huge is the file?

Comment: What is the objective reason for you saying that using "next() isn't an efficient way" of doing this?

Comment: @barny because for making the next "list2" I can't use the same approach. And I lose the control over the text file. Because I don't now what I am skipping.

Comment: @JoelCornett It is a topology of linessegments. Around thousands lines.

Comment: Does your file actually containing `N1 N2` and so on, or is rather `123 1234` followed by another line of numbers? Could you give an actual part of the file, say the first 15 lines or so?

Comment: So by 'not efficient' you actually mean 'not effective/doesn't work'. Surely, where each of your next statements is, you should split/append to n then p, shouldn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *partition* the file into groups of 3 lines:

```
# based on 'grouper()' example from the python 2 itertools documentation
from itertools import izip
def partition(lines, n):
    iters = [iter(lines)] * n
    return izip(*iters)
```

Thus doing `list(partition("ABCDEFGHI", 3))` would give you:

```
["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"]
```

Then, simply explode and rezip the result:

```
partitions = partition("ABCDEFGHI", 3)
splits = zip(*partitions)
```

So your code would end up looking somthing like this:

```
from itertools import izip, islice

def partition(lines, n):
    iters = [iter(lines)] * n
    return izip(*iters)

with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    keep = islice(f, 7, None) # drop the first 7 lines
    parts = partition(keep, 3) # partition into groups of 3
    groups = izip(*parts) # group the lines by their index % 3
    M, N, P = [sum((g.split() for g in group), []) for group in groups]
```

I've left out error checking/handling for simplicity's sake.

References:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#recipes

Comment: Python does have some mighty iterations operators, even though it reduces the readability somewhat!

Comment: @JoelCornett Thanks, it works perfect, just i replaced izip with zip in python 3.

Comment: @JoelCornett Why did you use sum except join for a list of strings? If we want to use join how does it work? I don't get exactly this line [sum((g.split() for g in group), []) for group in groups] what is group?

Comment: Because `str.join()` is for joining a list of strings into a single string. An example of `group` is `["M0 M", "M1 M2"]`. It is all of the line 1s grouped into a single list. Splitting the strings in `group` using `g.split() for g in group` gives us a list of lists: `[["M0", " M1"], ["M1", " M2"]]`. I then use `sum()` to concatenate the lists into a single list.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
counter = 0
with open('myfile.txt') as fh:
    for line in itertools.islice(fh, 7, None):
        row = line.strip().split()
        result[counter % 3].extend(row)
        counter += 1
```

`result` will be a dictionary (defaultdict) with keys `0`, `1` and `2`, containing the lists corresponding to your `m`, `n` and `p`. Of course you can change that, I just did it to avoid code repetition.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the stumbling block here is that you are reading lines in your loop command and struggling to separate m n and p. If this is the case then what I would suggest is getting a total number of lines out of your read file before starting your loop and use the range function -7 /3 (this would require a very strict adherence to your text file structure but would allow you to switch between three lines in every loop instance. See code below.

```
myfile = open('myfile.txt', 'r')

m,n,p = [], [], []


# Obtain line count from text file and work out iterations needed for loop

myfile_length = len(myfile.readlines())
iterations_needed = ((myfile_lenght-7)/3)
my_file.seek(0)


for i in range(7):   # Gets past those pesky first 7 lines
   myfile.readlines()


for x in range(iterations_needed):

    ll = my_file.readline()  # string  
    row = ll.split()  # list
    m.append(row[0]) # append first column of every third line
    m.append(row[1])

    ll = my_file.readline()  # string
    row = ll.split()  # list
    n.append(row[0]) 
    n.append(row[1])
    n.append(row[2])

    ll = my_file.readline()  # string
    row = ll.split()  # list
    p.append(row[0]) 
    p.append(row[1])


print(m)
print(n)
print(p)

myfile.close()
```

Hope this helps. You will have to add your error checking back in I removed it for simplicity. Also I have not compiled the code so syntax errors may be present. The bones of the fix are there.

Note you can cut the read line and split line to one line using:

```
read_file.readline().rstrip()
```

Comment: @ Paul Thanks for your answer. I avoid using readlines() because it load all the file in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

The basic flaw in your thinking, I think, is that you want to read all the first numeric lines, and then the second lines. It is better to read the file once through, and rather sort out the different lines whilst you read the file. One way to do this is to use a line counter mod 3 like in another answer, or you could continue reading lines within the for loop like the following:

```
myFileList= """first line
2nd line
3rd line
#Mi Mj
#Ni Nj Nk
#Pi Pj
#----------- The numeric values start here ------
M0 M1
N0 N1 N2
P0 P1
M1 M2
N1 N2 N3
P1 P2
M2 M3  
N2 N2 N3
P2 P3"""

myFakeFile = iter(myFileList.split('\n'))

m,n,p = [], [], []
m2, n2, p2 = [], [], []

# Skip the first few lines
for skip_lines in range(7):
    next(myFakeFile)

# Read the next line ...
for line in myFakeFile:

     # ... and the following two lines
    second_line = next(myFakeFile)
    third_line = next(myFakeFile)

    # Either append line directly, 
    m.append(line)
    n.append(second_line)
    p.append(third_line)

    # or split the lines before appending
    m2.extend(line.split())
    n2.extend(second_line.split())
    p2.extend(third_line.split())


print('m = {}'.format(m))
print('n = {}'.format(n))
print('p = {}\n'.format(p))

print('m2 = {}'.format(m2))
print('n2 = {}'.format(n2))
print('p2 = {}\n'.format(p2))
```

I was a little unsure if you wanted to split the actual lines another time, so therefore I added the `m2, n2, p2` lists showing that as well. And I had to fake the file to get a running example. But this code produces the following output:

```
m = ['M0 M1', 'M1 M2', 'M2 M3']
n = ['N0 N1 N2', 'N1 N2 N3', 'N2 N2 N3']
p = ['P0 P1', 'P1 P2', 'P2 P3']

m2 = ['M0', 'M1', 'M1', 'M2', 'M2', 'M3']
n2 = ['N0', 'N1', 'N2', 'N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N2', 'N2', 'N3']
p2 = ['P0', 'P1', 'P1', 'P2', 'P2', 'P3']
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, it works nicely, actually i want the m2, n2, p2 and later again i break them into smaller lists, but I vote for 1st solution because it is a clean and short code.

Answer (score 0):

```
fh = open('in.txt', 'r')

list1, list2, list3 = [], [], []


def get_list(num):
    return {
        0: list3,
        1: list1,
        2: list2,
    }[num]

count = 1

for i, line in enumerate(fh, 1):

    if (i < 7):
        continue

    get_list(count % 3).extend(line.rstrip().split())
    count += 1

print("{}\n{}\n{}".format(list1, list2, list3))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works but i prefer the first solution since using built in methods.